# Breakpoints not hit in Xcode (9.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

None of my breakpoints are being hit.

I've tried the following:

- Deleted Derived Data directory
- Cleaned build folder
- Deleted the xcuserdata directory
- Made sure build configuration is `Debug` and `Debug executable` is
  ticked
- Made sure   `Generate debug symbols` is set to `Yes`
- Changed `Optimization level` to `No optimization`

The breakpoints are still not being hit.

Answer (score 13):

Had this exact issue today - breakpoints in Swift projects were failing in XCode 9.3 (objective-c ones were fine).

The following fixed it:

> change Optimization level under the Swift Compiler - Code Generation submenu. Move it from -O to -Onone

[image]

src: https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/89nht7/breakpoints_not_working_after_updating_to_xcode_93/?st=jftp4n02&sh=49688058

Answer (score 10):

Try below steps

1. Go to debug (top bar in Xcode)
2. Debug Workflow
3. Always show Disassembly - uncheck it

Answer (score 6):

None of the existing answers worked for me so I dug into what was going on. By forcing a breakpoint in code (i.e. an asm("int3;") instruction) I was able to see that the symbols weren't loading. Naturally breakpoints depend on symbol information being loaded.

The code for which my breakpoints weren't working was in a C++ framework and the framework has a build setting called "**Strip linked product**" which was defaulted to "Yes" for both release and debug builds. By setting this to "No" for the debug build (and doing a full rebuild) my breakpoints now work again.

Answer (score 4):

I had set `Deployment Postprocessing` to `NO` in my Build Settings for my target. Setting this to `YES` made my breakpoints work again.

Comment: Weirdly enough, for me it was the opposite, setting `Deployment Postprocessing` to `NO` fixed breakpoints.

Answer (score 4):

In my case problem was in the **Debug information format** setting. It was set to `DWARF` instead of `DWARF with dSYM File`. Reseting it to the default value solved the problem.

Comment: This was it for me in XCode 12! Thanks a lot, I've spent a few hours trying to find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and this solution works for me:

- Open project settings
- Optimization Level
- Under "Swift Complier - Code Generation" Section
- Set "**Optimization Level**" to No **Optimization[-Onone]**

Refer attached screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check Preferences > Behaviors > Running > Pauses options.
The Show for navigator and debugger must have ticked.

Comment: They are ticked

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select breakpoint tab in XCode delete all the old breakpoints. 
Then add new breakpoints. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous solutions worked for me either.  I had an issue where all my breakpoints would work except on a c++ project among other projects in an xcode (9.4.1) workspace.  For that project, I noticed that only some breakpoints were working.  Digging deeper showed that it was breakpoints made within private methods that did not work.

After a good deal of investigation, I found my particular issue.  In my main project, I had declared some static objective-c initializers in a header file.  Not entirely sure why, but after I moved these to the implementation file where they were referenced, my broken breakpoints started working again.  Hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

Setting **Build Active Architecture Only** to **Yes** helps me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Deployment Postprocessing to "Yes" in my Build Settings for my target.
2. Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always show Disassembly -> Uncheck
3. Quit Xcode and reopen the Xcode.

[image]